# PDO while fetchColumn loop allowing zero

Tags: php, pdo

If `$id` is zero, the `while` statement skips the record.

How should it be revised so that even when `$id` is zero, it is not skipped?

```
while( $id=$stmt->fetchColumn() ) {
    // Do something even if $id is zero (but not false)
}
```

Comment: `while(($id=$stmt->fetchColumn()) !== false)`?

Comment: @u_mulder  Yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet which has type check as well

```
while(($id=$stmt->fetchColumn()) !== false){
    //Do something even if $id is zero (but not false)
}
```